# fast 5v High Side switch controlled bz 3.3v

Tags: switches, load, high-speed

For my led cube, I need to switch 5V (common anode layers) with 3.3v (pic32). This should happen at a high frequency. In recent builds I used pfets, but because I'm using 3.3v now, a pfet wouldn't really completely shut down. I want to switch high side since I'm using stp16s for controlling the low side.
What IC/method would you suggest for switching the led planes? I target a frequency in the MHz's.

Comment: How much current?

Comment: A P-FET will shut down completely if you use an N-FET or NPN BJT to switch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a level-translator.  There are many available but a common part is a 74HCT541 (older) or SN74LVC4245A (newer).  Both of these have 8 channels.  In general, you could use almost any of the HCT parts - the "T" specifies that the gate / buffer input is TTL compatible: less than 0.8V for a logic LO, greater than 2.4V for a logic HI.

Comment: Can they supply enough current to charge the mosfet Gates?

Comment: Perhaps.  Some of those chips are good for almost 100mA peak current.  Whether that is enough depends on your FETs.  But in general, if you were getting good performance driving those FETs directly with your micro previously, these will work better.